# How to set YouTube video monetization programticly

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am able to upload videos to YouTube using the API, however I have been unable to find out how to enable monetize for my video using API.

[Videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) does not appear to have any way of setting this.  Nor can I find any more information on how to set it in the documentation.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To enable monetization you need to use the Google Content Owner API, which is available to those with a Content Owner account.  [YouTube Partner Program overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/)

Once you have your content owner id you should be able to do something like this

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/claims?onBehalfOfContentOwner=CONTENT_OWNER_ID
Authorization: Bearer ...

{
  "assetId": "ASSET_ID",
  "videoId": "VIDEO_ID",
  "policy": {
    "id": "POLICY_ID"
  },
  "contentType": "audiovisual"
}
```